# In Foundry, how can I Hive partition with only 1 parquet file per value?

Tags: pyspark, palantir-foundry, hive-partitions, foundry-code-repositories, foundry-code-workbooks

I'm looking to improve the performance on running filtering logic.   To accomplish this, the idea is to do hive partitioning setting by setting the partition column to a column in the dataset (called `splittable_column`).

I checked and the cardinality of splittable column is low, and if I subset each value from `splitting_column`, the end result is a 800MB parquet file.

If the cardinality of my dataset is 3, my goal is to have the data laid out like:

```
spark/splittable_column=Value A/part-00000-abc.c000.snappy.parquet  
spark/splittable_column=Value B/part-00000-def.c000.snappy.parquet  
spark/splittable_column=Value C/part-00000-ghi.c000.snappy.parquet
```

When I run `my_output_df.write_dataframe(df_with_logic,partition_cols=["splittable_column"])`, and look at the results, I see many files in the KB range within the directory, which is going to cause a large overhead during reading.  For example my dataset looks like:

```
spark/splittable_column=Value A/part-00000-abc.c000.snappy.parquet
spark/splittable_column=Value A/part-00001-abc.c000.snappy.parquet  
spark/splittable_column=Value A/part-00002-abc.c000.snappy.parquet  
...
spark/splittable_column=Value A/part-00033-abc.c000.snappy.parquet  
spark/splittable_column=Value B/part-00000-def.c000.snappy.parquet
...
spark/splittable_column=Value B/part-00030-def.c000.snappy.parquet
spark/splittable_column=Value C/part-00000-ghi.c000.snappy.parquet
...
spark/splittable_column=Value C/part-00032-ghi.c000.snappy.parquet
etc.
```

From the documentation I understand that:

> you will have **at least** one output file for each unique value in your partition column

How do I configure the transform that I get at most 1 output file per task during Hive partitioning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the input data, you may notice that the data is split across multiple parquet files.  When you look at the build report for just running  `my_output_df.write_dataframe(df_with_logic,partition_cols=["splittable_column"])`, you may notice that there is no shuffle in the query plan.

IE, you would see:

Graph:

```
Scan
Project
BasicStats
Execute
```

Plan:

```
FoundrySaveDatasetCommand `ri.foundry.main.transaction.xxx@master`.`ri.foundry.main.dataset.yyy`, ErrorIfExists, [column1 ... 17 more fields],
+- BasicStatsNode `ri.foundry.main.transaction.zzz@master`.`ri.foundry.main.dataset.aaa`
   +- Project [splitable_column ... 17 more fields]
      +- Relation !ri.foundry.main.transaction.xxx:master.ri.foundry.main.dataset.yyy[splittable_column... 17 more fields] parquet
```

In this example, it only took 1 minute to run because there was no shuffle.

Now if you repartition on the column you are going to partition by:

```
df_with_logic = df_with_logic.repartition("splittable_column")
my_output_df.write_dataframe(df_with_logic,partition_cols=["splittable_column"]
```

It will force an `Exchange`, ie `RepartitionByExpression` on `splittable_column`, which will take longer (15 minutes in my case) but the data will be split the way I wanted:

```
spark/splittable_column=Value A/part-00000-abc.c000.snappy.parquet  
spark/splittable_column=Value B/part-00000-def.c000.snappy.parquet  
spark/splittable_column=Value C/part-00000-ghi.c000.snappy.parquet
```

Graph:

```
Scan
Exchange
Project
BasicStats
Execute
```

Plan:

```
ri.foundry.main.transaction.xxx@master`.`ri.foundry.main.dataset.yyy`, ErrorIfExists, [column1 ... 17 more fields],
+- BasicStatsNode `ri.foundry.main.transaction.zzz@master`.`ri.foundry.main.dataset.aaa`
   +- Project [splitable_column ... 17 more fields]
      +- RepartitionByExpression [splittable_column], 1
          +- Relation !ri.foundry.main.transaction.xxx:master.ri.foundry.main.dataset.yyy[splittable_column... 17 more fields] parquet
```